# svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/svn': Could not read status line: Operation timed out (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)

Tags: apache, http, svn, webdav, centos6

I have a problem continue to burn my head from two days.

I setup a SVN on my centos6.3 hosted on a dedicated server. I'm used to deploy SVN with web_dav but that time it's not gonna work as expected.

Actually the repository work throughout the web-brwoser, but impossible to make it work by command line or any tools, I get

```
svn co http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/svn
Authentication realm: <http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80> Authorization Realm
Password for 'xxxxxx': 
svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/svn': Could not read status line: Operation timed out (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

even I succeed to get the Authentication prompt and Apache access_log show

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - Atheryl [16/Feb/2014:06:09:33 -0500] "OPTIONS /svn HTTP/1.1" 200 183 "-" "SVN/1.7.10 neon/0.29.6"
```

I tried from other machine/os/location in the world ...

My httpd.conf have just the servername modified and here is my subversion.conf

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /var/www/svn/repos
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorization Realm"
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I did, as well during installation

```
chkconfig --level 235 httpd on
```

I did contact the support of this server for another reason (Two domain name pointing to my IP address, they changed my server addresses so now logs are clear.)

If anyone have any tip for me, thank you.

Edit :

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have ordinary connection timeout **and** redirect-loop (timeout can be result of loop)

Where you have defined web-root in Apache? Is it (haphazardly) `/var/www/` (check `DocumentRoot` directive in main-host container)? If my assumption is correct, your config is exclusively bad - you have real physical localtion `/svn` under web-root, logical Location `/svn` (overlapped physical) and repositories *as ordinary trees*, accessible by Apache (it's terrible incorrect and absolutely insecure)

**Move** tree `/var/www/svn/repos/` into any other location in host outside web-root, edit `SVNPath` accordinly. As result you must have /some/path/to/repo (**single repo** at this path, because SVNPath used) in config and directory `/var/www/svn/` **must not exist** in your FS

`chkconfig` will not find any errors, because your config is syntactically correct, but contain logical error(s)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. My DocumentRoot is "/var/www/html".

Comment: Any changes to see *restrictive* firewall in the middle? Try to access localhost by svn-client (on CentOS), if you can

Comment: Actually i can checkout from the machine itself. Is that the question ? I didn't modify anything from the installation, I was thinking about a firewall in the Datacenter ... but how to explain it to the host :/

Comment: @Atheryl - if you try to use hostname (localhost rles usually aren't restrictive, even if exist) of you CentOS host for checkout (working *locally on it*) and it will be successful, you can eliminate  *your* possible local misconfiguration, and disfunction of remote command in this case is only "Man in the middle" intervention. You can explain exactly this way "Work locally, doesn't work if communication crossed the border, HOSTER's border, which you can't control"

Comment: Let's wait for their reply. I did wait 3 days for an IP address change last time a Domain point to my server so ...

Comment: They said that the port is open, end of discussion ^^. So ... I'm still searching